# ¿ Como cambiar la imagen de un boton que tiene 2 estados desde el lado del servidor?

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un botón en HTML donde la imagen la coge de un CSS. Cuando pulso el botón debe cambiar a otra imagen y si lo pulso de nuevo debe volver a la anterior imagen que tenia.

¿ Como hacerlo desde el lado del servidor ?
¿ Es mas correcto hacerlo desde el servidor o desde el cliente con JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ASP.NET podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:Button ID="MiBotonActivador" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="uncheck" OnClick="Toogle_Check" />
```

Y dentro de tu `<script runat="server">` pones la siguiente función (o su equivalente según si estas utilizando C# o Basic):

```
protected void Toogle_Check(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(Body.Attributes("class").Contains("uncheck")) {
        MiBotonActivador.CssClass = "check";
    } else {
        MiBotonActivador.CssClass = "uncheck";
    }
}
```

Ahora lo unico que tienes que hacer es establecer la imagen de fondo del botón por medio de las clases `check` y `uncheck` respectivamente:

```
button.uncheck {
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678069-sign-error-512.png");
}

button.check {
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-512.png");
}
```

La verdad hace mucho que no hago nada en ASP.net así que el codigo de arriba puede contener algún error o puede no funcionar como se espera. Yo te recomendiendo hacerlo con Javascript usando JQuery:

```js
function toogleCheck(button) {
  var c = button.data("check"),
      u = button.data("uncheck"),
      s = button.data("status");
      
  if(s === "0") {
    button.css("background-image", "url(" + u + ")");
    button.data("status", "1");
  } else {
    button.css("background-image", "url(" + c + ")");
    button.data("status", "0");
  }
}

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    toogleCheck($("button"));
    $("button").on("click", function(){
      toogleCheck($(this));
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fab153;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-status="0" data-check="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-512.png" data-uncheck="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678069-sign-error-512.png"></button>
```

También puedes hacerlo mezclando CSS y JS de la siguiente manera:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("check").toggleClass("uncheck");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fab153;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}

button.uncheck {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678069-sign-error-512.png");
}

button.check {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-512.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="uncheck"></button>
```

Saludos!

Comment: En caso de usar JavaScript no quiero usar jQuery. Me interesaría mas hacerlo desde el servidor con runat = "server"

Comment: Hola @Popularfan he añadido un ejemplo con ASP.NET, espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Como se adaptaría la solución en JQuery pero solo con JavaScript?

Comment: Alfinal encontré una solución en JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una solución en JavaScript que funciona pero con un comportamiento extraño al principio. La primera vez que cargo la pagina y pulso el botón hay como un tiempo entre pasar de la primera imagen a la otra. En el espacio de ese tiempo se ve blanco. Si luego voy pulsando repetidamente el cambio es instantáneo.

```
function btnToogle() {
  if (document.getElementById('btn1').getAttribute('class') == 'cssboton1')
   document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute('cssboton2');
  else 
   document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute('cssboton1');
}
```